# How can I modify angularjs transcluded element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have parent-directive and child-directive. I'm using ng-transculde.

```
<parent-directive>
    <child-directive type="SOME_TYPE" 
                     class="child"
                     options="{fooId: vm.fooId, fooType: vm.fooType}">
    </child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

I want to set child-directive "id" from parent directive.
Now I'm trying to do like this:

```
.directive('parentDirective', function ($rootScope, fileService) {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                disabled: "=?"
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                document.getElementById('transcluded_content').firstElementChild.id = 'myId'
            },
            template: '<div><ng-transclude id="transcluded_content"></ng-transclude></div>'
        };
    })
```

It shows error `TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'id')`
I tried many ways and everytime it shows errors. I think I don't understand logic or I don't know method to use. Please help me...

Comment: if I try to view length of child elements `console.log(document.getElementById('transcluded_content').getElementsByTagName('child-directive').length)` it show '0'. But I know that it is wrong. I think it can't keep up.

Comment: I tried to do like this(temporary added class, to make any modification to child): `link: function (scope, elm, attrs,ctrl,transclude) {
                transclude(scope,function(clone) {
                    clone.filter('child-directive').addClass('reddos');
                    elm.append(clone);
                });
            }` it also doesn't work

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `document.getElementById()` because you already have the `element` variable to use. For the sake of troubleshooting, try `console.log(element.html())` in the link function and see what you get.